# Clicking on Overlays in MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I've created a MapActivity that uses MapView to place drawables on an ArrayList of points I've specified.  This works great.

I want the user to be able to press each point and have a bubble appear (as when you are using Google Maps in your web browser) with some information about that point.

I can not figure out how to do this.  Could someone point me to some good resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ItemizedOverlay`, just override `onTap()` in your overlay class. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) demonstrating this.

The relevant snippet there is:

```
    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(NooYawk.this, items.get(i).getSnippet(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return(true);
    }
```

Instead of displaying a `Toast`, you can do something else. For example, [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/EvenNooerYawk) that displays a popup. And [here's an Android library project](https://github.com/donnfelker/android-mapviewballoons) that displays bubbles that point to the actual marker.